# Divide a form in two columns

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I'm trying to divide my checkout form in two columns (Twitter Bootstrap), but it doesn't really work out.

When I enter all the required information, it says that the fields aren't filled as required. I'm guessing it's got something to do with the form script being loaded two times.

Here's the code and where I'm trying to divide it:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

            <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-2">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

            <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to divide it here:

```
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

        <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

To see the page that I'm trying to edit, go to [link](http://mimac.weshape.dk/produkt/brun-hardcase/) and add the product to the cart. Then go here [link](http://mimac.weshape.dk/betaling/)

Comment: Give the link to the page which would have this.

Comment: @ManojKumar - It's at the checkout page. So you will have to go add a product to the cart here: http://mimac.weshape.dk/produkt/brun-hardcase/ and then go here: http://mimac.weshape.dk/betaling/

Comment: You want something like this? http://prntscr.com/83pcnr